# check 2 files c code

Tags: c, file

I am working in c.
I have two files. I would like to ask what's the best way to test in each line from the first file if exists in the second file.

I also need some example codes.

Thx

Comment: How large will the files be (maximum number of lines, maximum number of characters per line)?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The best way is to get each file contents, look if lines for the first one appear in the second one, and you're done. Judging by what you said you try and the code you gave us as an example of your problem, you might have trouble understanding this, but keep trying and someday you'll achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a diffviewer instead of coding it yourself?

http://meldmerge.org/

Otherwise, in C, compare characters from beginning to end, remember the differences at respective position and print them out?

Comment: Maybe OP just need to test existence and not order ? For example a file containing `a\nb\nc` might match a file containing `b\nc\nd\na`

Comment: *test in each line from the first file if exists in the second file.* He does not want to check if the files are identical. This looks more like finding a list of lines among a full file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is a little vague, "hash" could be an answer that is also a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int compareFiles(const char * filename_compared, const char *filename_checked, int *matched)
{
    int matches = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    char compare_line[10000];
    char check_line[10000];

    char *compare;
    char *check;
    FILE *f_compare;
    FILE *f_check;

    f_compare = fopen(filename_compared,"r");
    if ( f_compare == NULL ) 
    {  
        printf("ERROR %d opening %s\n",errno,filename_compared); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    } else { printf("opened %s\n",filename_compared); }

    f_check = fopen(filename_checked,"r");
    if ( f_check == NULL )  
    {  
        printf("ERROR %d opening %s\n",errno,filename_checked); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE; 
    } else { printf("opened %s\n",filename_checked); }
    compare = fgets(compare_line,sizeof(compare_line),f_compare);
    while (  ! feof(f_compare)  )
    {
       lines++;
       fseek(f_check,0,0);
       check = fgets(check_line,sizeof(check_line),f_check);
       while (  ! feof(f_check) )
       {
          if ( strcmp(compare_line,check_line) == 0 )
          {
             matches++;
             break;
          }
          check = fgets(check_line,sizeof(check_line),f_check);
       }
       compare = fgets(compare_line,sizeof(compare_line),f_compare);  
    } 
    *matched = matches;
    printf("%d lines read in first file and %d lines matched a line in the 2nd file\n",lines,matches);
    fclose(f_check);
    fclose(f_compare);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int matches;
    if ( argc < 3 )
    {
       printf("ERROR: You must enter the two input filenames\n");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int return_code = compareFiles(argv[1],argv[2],&matches);
    if ( return_code == EXIT_SUCCESS )
        printf("%d lines in %s matched a line in %s\n",matches, argv[1],argv[2]);
    else
       printf("there was an error in processing the files\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Angela, just study the C book you where pointed to for doing this just homework assignment. It just likely has a whole chapter just on file handling.

You need to get yourself acquainted with fopen (and fclose), fscanf, fseek, and possibly memcmp, for starters.